# Algoritmo recursivo laberinto

Tags: c, recursión

Buenas , me encuentro ante un problema recursivo para encontrar la salida de un laberinto en una matriz bidimensional. La leyenda de este laberinto es:

```
'E' = entrada
'S' = salida
'#' = pared
' ' = camino
```

La idea es que el programa me marque un camino que vaya desde la entrada a la salida y lo marque con el caracter 'O'. El laberinto de la matriz esta perfectamente generado y coge sin problema la posicion de la entrada y la salida en el mismo
Habia pensado en implementarlo utilizando el backtracking pero no consigo aplicarlo correctamente dado que no consigo hacerme a la idea de como puedo ejecutarlo para que funcione correctamente. ¿Alguna idea de como implementarlo?

Struct:

```
typedef struct{
  char Laberinto[FIL][COL];
}Tablero;
```

Subprograma recursivo para salir

```
void salir (int x,int y,int *resultado_x,int *resultado_y , Tablero *tab) 
{
  x = entrx; //Coordenada x de la entrada
  y = entry; //Coordenada y de la entrada

  if(tab->Laberinto[x][y]==' ') //camino libre { tab->Laberinto[x][y]=3;
   salir(x+1,y,resultado_x,resultado_y, &*tab);
   salir(x-1,y,resultado_x,resultado_y ,&*tab);
   salir(x,y+1,resultado_x,resultado_y ,&*tab);
   salir(x,y-1,resultado_x,resultado_y ,&*tab); }
  if(tab->Laberinto[x][y]=='#') //pared 
  { return; }
  if(tab->Laberinto[x][y]=='o') //ya estuve aqui 
  { return; }
  if(tab->Laberinto[x][y]=='S') //encontre la salida {
   *resultado_x=x;
   *resultado_y=y; return; } 
}
```

Subprograma que me genera el tablero y me encuentra las coordenadas de la entrada

```
void EncontrarEntradas(Tablero *tab) {

 int i , j , x , y;
 int entrada = 0
 int entrx = 0, entry = 0;
 int resultado_x = 0 , resultado_y = 0;

 for(i = 0; i < FIL-1; i++)
 {
   for (j = 0; j < COL; j++ )
   {
         printf("%c",tab->Laberinto[i][j]);

         if (tab->Laberinto[i][j] == 'S')
         {
             salx = j;
             saly = i;
             salida = 1;

         }
         if (tab->Laberinto[i][j] == 'E')
         {
             x = j;
             y = i;
             entrada = 1;
         }

   }
 }


 salir(x,y,&resultado_x,&resultado_y , &tab);

}
```

Comment: Si no consigues aplicarlo quiere decir que algo has probado... ¿Por qué no empiezas poniendo ese código? Si no publicas nada parecerá que estás pidiendo que te hagamos los deberes y no te gustará que pensemos eso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu algoritmo no tiene mucho sentido. Lo que estás intentando es inundar todos los posibles caminos cuando deberías quedarte con solo uno. La idea tendría que ser algo similar a:

- si estoy en la casilla de meta, retorno 1
- si estoy en una pared o en una casilla con `'o'` o en la casilla de entrada, retorno 0
- si estoy en la casilla de entrada:

  - si ya he pasado por la misma, retorno 0 (el camino anterior no es válido)
  - pruebo a llamar recursivamente a la función para probar arriba
  - pruebo a llamar recursivamente a la función para probar abajo
  - pruebo a llamar recursivamente a la función para probar izquierda
  - pruebo a llamar recursivamente a la función para probar derecha
  - algun camino debería ser solucion pero bueno, procesar este caso queda a tu juicio
- si estoy en un pasillo:

  - lo marco con la `'o'`
  - pruebo a llamar recursivamente a la función para probar arriba
  - pruebo a llamar recursivamente a la función para probar abajo
  - pruebo a llamar recursivamente a la función para probar izquierda
  - pruebo a llamar recursivamente a la función para probar derecha
  - si las cuatro llamadas me devuelve 0 esta casilla no esta en el camino de salida, sustituyo el `'o'` por `' '` y retorno 0
  - si cualquiera de las 4 llamadas anteriores me devuelve 1 es que he encontrado la salida, retorno 1

Además, no veo razón para que la función recursiva devuelva unas coordenadas. ¿Coordenadas a dónde? ¿A la salida? ¿A cada iteración? ¿?

Es decir, para permitir deshacer las rutas incorrectas, la función debería tener una firma tal que:

```
    int salir(int x,int y,Tablero *tab) 
 // ^^^
 // Importante!!!
```

¿Y cómo implementarla? Siguiendo los pasos anteriores es sencilla

```
int salir (int x,int y,Tablero *tab,int primero)
{
  char* c = &tab->Laberinto[x][y];

  if( *c == 'S' )
    return 1;
  else if( *c == 'E' )
  {
    if( primero )
      if( salir(x+1,y,tab,0) || salir(x-1,y,tab,0) || salir(x,y+1,tab,0) || salir(x,y-1,tab,0) )
        return 1;
  }
  else if( *c == ' ' )
  {
    *c = 'o';
    if( salir(x+1,y,tab,0) || salir(x-1,y,tab,0) || salir(x,y+1,tab,0) || salir(x,y-1,tab,0) )
      return 1;
    else
    {
      if( *c == 'o' )
        *c = ' ';
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

El nuevo argumento que ha aparecido en la función sirve para impedir que el algoritmo pueda saltar por la `'E'` un número indefinido de veces. Solo se va a permitir que la primera llamada este posicionada sobre esta letra.

Adicionalmente tu función para encontrar el punto de entrada al laberinto tiene errores:

```
void EncontrarEntradas(Tablero *tab) {

  int i , j , x , y;
  int entrada = 0
  int entrx = 0, entry = 0;
  int resultado_x = 0 , resultado_y = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < FIL-1; i++) // <<--- ¿Por que no verificas la ultima fila?
  {
    for (j = 0; j < COL; j++ )
    {
      if (tab->Laberinto[i][j] == 'E')
      {
        x = j; // <<--- esta deberia ser i
        y = i; // <<--- esta deberia ser j
        entrada = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  salir(x,y,&tab,1); // Asi se deberia llamar ahora a la funcion recursiva
}
```